# dd wrt suddenly dropping all wifi clients every few minutes

Tags: dd-wrt

A few hours ago I made a configuration change on my ddwrt instance, removing an iptables command from the firewall command settings, and turning off the OpenVpn client. Since then DD WRT has been acting up. It drops all wifi clients every few minutes. I can see it on the clients themselves, as well as on the DDWRT Wireless Status page, where "active clients" suddenly drops to 0.

I can't figure out what happened to cause this, and I don't see any errors in the logs. But I do see a bunch of warnings for:

```
Invalid peer id 255 in peer stats buffer
Rekeying PTK for STA d8:13:99:82:0a:6f but driver can't safely do that.
```

Comment: what authentication method did you set up for your router? Also, have you tried DD-WRT forum? I've found they are very helpful. By the way, I typed "Rekeying PTK for STA error in DD-WRT" into bing on edge ... very useful info